# Check if file exists on remote HDFS from local spark-submit

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I'm working on a Java program dedicated to work with Spark on a HDFS filesystem (located at `HDFS_IP`).
One of my goals is to check whether a file exists on the HDFS at path `hdfs://HDFS_IP:HDFS_PORT/path/to/file.json`. While debugging my program in local, I figured out I can't access to this remote file using the following code

```java
private boolean existsOnHDFS(String path) {
     Configuration conf = new Configuration();
     FileSystem fs;
     Boolean fileDoesExist = false ;
     try {
         fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
         fileDoesExist = fs.exists(new Path(path)) ;
     } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return fileDoesExist ;
 }
```

Actually, `fs.exists` tries to look for the file `hdfs://HDFS_IP:HDFS_PORT/path/to/file.json` in my local FS and not on the HDFS. BTW letting the `hdfs://HDFS_IP:HDFS_PORT` prefix makes `fs.exists`crash and suppressing it answers `false` because `/path/to/file.json` does not exist locally.

What would be the appropriate configuration of `fs` to get things work properly in local and when executing the Java program from a Hadoop cluster ?

EDIT: I finally gave up and passed the bugfix to someone else in my team. Thanks to the people who tried to help me though !

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you passing to FileSystem an empty conf file.

You should create your FileSystem like that:

```
FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration());
```

when spark is the SparkSession object.

As you can see in the code of FileSystem:

```
 /**
   * Returns the configured filesystem implementation.
   * @param conf the configuration to use
   */
  public static FileSystem get(Configuration conf) throws IOException {
    return get(getDefaultUri(conf), conf);
  }

  /** Get the default filesystem URI from a configuration.
   * @param conf the configuration to use
   * @return the uri of the default filesystem
   */
  public static URI getDefaultUri(Configuration conf) {
    return URI.create(fixName(conf.get(FS_DEFAULT_NAME_KEY, DEFAULT_FS)));
  }
```

it creates the URI base on the configuration passed as parameter, it looks for the key FS_DEFAULT_NAME_KEY(fs.defaultFS) when the DEFAULT_FS is:

```
  public static final String  FS_DEFAULT_NAME_DEFAULT = "file:///";
```

Comment: Thanks ShemTov. I used my `spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration()` to create my `FileSystem` object but `fs.exists` still looks into my local storage rather than the HDFS. Do you have another idea ?

Comment: Yes, i guess it is because your local environment doesn`t have the hdfs-site.xml / core-site.xml in the resources. you can solve it in two ways:
1. Add hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml to resources directory (if you are using intellij press right click on the directory -> mark directory as resources).
2. Little cheaty but you can do spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://server:port/") and then pass it to FileSystem.get().
I will prefer option number one.